# Nested ULs wrapping

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I got an HTML string that I need to parse (to be used in Flash), by wrapping nested UL tags by a span with incremented `left-margin` value based on nesting level.

**Before:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two:
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two
                <ul>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item three
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item four</li>
</ul>
```

**After:**

```
<span style="left-margin:0px">
    <ul>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item two:
            <span style="left-margin:30px">
                <ul>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two
                        <span style="left-margin:60px">
                            <ul>
                                <li>One</li>
                                <li>Two</li>
                            </ul>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>Item three
            <span style="left-margin:30px">
                <ul>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>Item four</li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Note the incremented value: 0, 30, 60...

I did a (nasty) ActionScript solution, but I think there must be some elegant way to do it.

Comment: What sort of horrible system do you have that requires you to wrap ul elements with span elements (given that span elements may not have ul elements as children)?

Answer (score 0):

Since they are nested the margins should not have to be incremented.. each one starts from its nest level so it would add to the current margin ..

Putting `left-margin:30px;` to all span should do it ..

Not sure if you have other CSS definitions that might interfere with that,though.. so please elaborate..

Comment: I need to increment the margin, since I'll be using it in a Flash text field, which doesn't render HTML the same way a browser does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this. Put the nested list in some container element and run this on that container element:

```
function recursiveIndentation(element, indentation, increasingIndentation) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i = i + 1) {
        if (element.childNodes[i].nodeName === "UL") {
            var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
            span.style.marginLeft = indentation + "px";
            element.insertBefore(span, element.childNodes[i])
            span.appendChild(element.childNodes[i + 1]);
            recursiveIndentation(span.childNodes[0], indentation + increasingIndentation, increasingIndentation);
        } else {
            recursiveIndentation(element.childNodes[i], indentation, increasingIndentation);
        }
    }
}
```

The innerHtml attribute of your container element will now hold the string you need.

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS-only solution:

```
ul { margin-left: 0 }
ul ul { margin-left: 30px }
ul ul ul { margin-left: 60px }
ul ul ul ul { margin-left: 90px }
```

Not pretty/generic/what you asked for, but it's at least very simple and may be good enough.

Comment: Since this will be used in flash, there's no way I can use CSS like the above.